# Как отличить разные типы nil

Tags: golang

Есть достаточно просто код:

```
package main

import "log"

type Object struct {
    Data interface{}
}

func NewObject(data interface{}) (o *Object) {
    o = &Object{Data: data}
    log.Printf("Object(%+v → its nil %v)", o.Data, o.Data == nil)
    return
}

func main() {
    var data *struct{}

    _ = NewObject(nil)
    _ = NewObject(data)
}
```

ссылка на playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fXWr5rjeq1T

При запуске получаем:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Object(<nil> → its nil true)
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Object(<nil> → its nil false)
```

То есть в  обоих случаях мы передаем в конструктор `nil`, но в первом случае это действительно `nil` а во втором не как бы не совсем :-)

Вопрос как отличать один случай от другого?

Comment: P.S. Про https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error читал, понимаю что проблема достаточно глобальная, и можно решить только через `reflection`. Но может существет еще како-нибудь подход?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если `interface{}` равен `nil`, значит этот интерфейс не содержит ни типа, ни значения. Остальное проверяется после приведения типов или через рефлексию. Есть несколько типов, когда `interface` не равен `nil` но при этом может содержать `nil`

1. канал (`chan`)
2. функция (`func`)
3. хэш-тблица (`map`)
4. указатель (`*X`)
5. отрезок (слайс) (`[]byte`)

Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/Wu58rw4UwG5)

Это значит, что `interface` содержит не нулевой тип, но указатель на значение при этом нулевой. В таком случае, узнать содержит ли `interface`, не равный нулю, нулевое значение или нет можно двумя способами.

1. После приведения типов, если набор входных типов известен заранее. Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/ug8ZZ1VGsov)
2. Используя рефлексию.

```golang
func isNil(ifc interface{}) bool {
    if ifc == nil {
        return true // просто возвращаем true если это нулевой interface
    }
    var val = reflect.ValueOf(ifc)
    // если не проверить, то возможна паника
    switch val.Kind() {
    case reflect.Chan, reflect.Func, reflect.Map, reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice:
        return val.IsNil()
    default:
    }
    return false // не может быть nil
}
```

Пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/yySObNkU-MN)

Comment: Посмотрите сюда: [50 оттенков go, пункт 54][1]

  [1]: https://habr.com/ru/company/mailru/blog/314804/#54

Comment: @softland, это уход от сути. Главное понимать, что `interface{}` это структура вида `{ *Type, *Value }` и `nil` она тогда, когда оба указателя `nil`.

Comment: Вы правы.
я хотел постеру подсказать полезный ресурс.